# How to set Minimum Tls version

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

How can we set minimum tls version as 1.2 and Network connectivity to Public Endpoint (Selected network) while creating storage account through Terraform ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/storage_account.html#example-usage-with-network-rules) is an example of Usage with Network Rules for `azurerm_storage_account`. To set minimum tls version as 1.2, you can use block `min_tls_version`. By default, the block `network_rules` is used for a public endpoint to a storage account. You can select to allow or deny some networks.

[image]

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "virtnetname"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "subnetname"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefix       = "10.0.2.0/24"
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Sql", "Microsoft.Storage"]
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                = "storageaccountname123"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"

  min_tls_version = "TLS1_2"

  network_rules {
    default_action             = "Deny"
    ip_rules                   = ["100.0.0.1"]
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = [azurerm_subnet.example.id]
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}
```

### Result

[image]

### Version

You could check the terraform version or you can upgrade to latest terraform via https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html

[image]

### Provider

```
provider "azurerm" {

  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
  client_id       = var.client_id
  client_secret   = var.client_secret
  tenant_id       = var.tenant_id


  features {}

}
```

Comment: What's the terraform version are your using? You could show that with running`terraform -v`. Please check my update.

Comment: I am using terraform v.0.13 or could you show all your codes? How do you use that? Can you directly copy my code then run it again?

Comment: Since you are using module file, for the error`An argument named "min_tls_version" is not expected here.`, you need to define a variable named `min_tls_version` in your module storage account configuration file.

Comment: There are no resource "azurerm_storage_account_network_rules"? Any link?

Comment: I see, Both function is the same. it's just a sperate resource for network rules. but the two cannot be used together.

Comment: Glad this helps you. please accept this reply. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).